# How to use tor with selenium-webdriver in python in a windows machine?

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, tor

I want to be able to write a instagram bot to auto comment on pictures.
I already figured the normal bot part out but i don t know how to use the tor webdriver so i will be able to change my ip address regulary so instagram won t be able to block me.

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
with TorBrowserDriver(r"\\C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser") as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I tried that but it said:

```
tbselenium.exceptions.TBDriverPathError: TBB path is not a directory \\C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\
```

Any answer is apreciated!!
:)

### Edit:

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver 
with TorBrowserDriver(r"\\C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser") as driver: 
driver.get("google.com")
```

```
tbselenium.exceptions.TBDriverPathError: TBB path is not a directory \\C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible with the standard `selenium` package.

You can try using [this](https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium) github repository, which can be installed with `pip install tbselenium`

**Note** that I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you tried?

Comment: It is in the question  from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver with TorBrowserDriver(r"\\C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser") as driver: driver.get("https://www.google.com")

Comment: Please don't post code in comments!  I edited your question with the code you provided.

Comment: Also, what error did you get when you ran this code?

Answer (score 1):

tbselenium will not work for you because of the compatibility,look at the project description https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium. Windows and macOS are not supported.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).